# Stuck on [131/416] test_faulthandler when installing Python 3.7 on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, installation, python-3.7, raspberry-pi4

Python 3.7 Installation is always halted by test_faulthandler upon running

```
make -j 4
```

I've waiting many hours to no avail, I also tried to cancel and try again but didn't work either.

Comment: Are there any error logs or additional data you can provide? What version did you download and which format.
Also, isn't Python 3.7 installed by default on Raspbian? Or are you using another OS?

Comment: It went through every other test but stopped at 131/416 which was test_faulthandler. I was following this: https://krystof.io/installing-alternative-python-versions-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: The tutorial is for 3.8.0, you said Python 3.7 in your title. Is that a typo?
Also, can you please add all the commands and error messages you used to the question? Maybe even just copy you terminal text when this occurs. This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: This was the terminal text
0:19:16 load avg: 0.95 [129/416] test_exception_variation 0:19:17 load avg: 0.96 [130/416] test_extcall 0:19:17 load avg: 0.96 [131/416] test_faulthandler

Also I copied the commands from the tutorial but changed all the commands to 3.7.0 instead of 3.8.0

Answer (score 1):

I had that too every time.. it's just running tests so not that necessary. Just run `sudo make altinstall` and you are good to go.